# How to find brightest point from no ir filter camera with visible light filter?

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, infrared

Can one find the brightest point in terms of IR (such as the sun or an IR led) from a camera with no-IR filter such as the rpi-camera 3 noir with an added visible light filter or similar, with something like a raspberry-pi or even a microcontroller?

This would be for use with an imu to find position relative to a set of IR LEDs at known spacings. The idea is to create something similar to the wii-mote ir camera with the bar, but at a higher resolution for more accuracy and more importantly, more range.

Comment: Please consider writing a lot more about the application. I've no idea where to go from the description, so far.

Comment: if you have access to the raw file, or to a lesser extent even the composite output, separate the image's red channel. Red will have red and IR light visible, whereas green and blue will block virtually all the IR. a "750 photo filter" would help further and keep out most visible, without the cost of a true IR filter.

Comment: Have to agree with the request for a lot more information about the application. For example I don't understand "camera with no-IR filter such as the rpi-camera 3 noir with an added visible light filter". 

The standard Pi camera includes the filter while the NOIR deletes the filter. Both cameras will operate in daylight and interface with a Raspberry Pi which could perform the analysis.

Comment: @PDP11 sorry for confusion. What I mean is the noir-rpi-camera with an extra visible light filter, so that only ir gets through

Comment: @wandyrge the visible light filter is irrelevant to the question ... it just adds clutter and confusion to the question

Comment: @jsotola why is that? Wouldn't the lack of a visible light filter mean that it would be harder to obtain the IR data by itself, since there would be additional brightness values which aren't relevant to the application?